# Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework" attribute names are case-sensitive

Tags: asp.net, iis

This is a common error and has been discussed many times here on SO.  But before sending me to the other answers please read the situation below. This isn't a case of the wrong framework being targeted.

EDIT: The error occurs if the web.config targets "4.0" or "4.0.3", either one.

In Visual Studio 2010 (on Win 7 x64) I have gone into the Advanced Compile Options and chosen "Install other Frameworks" from the Target Frameworks dropdown list. This procedure downloads the 4.0.3 framework from the Microsoft website. The installation processes takes several minutes and requires a reboot.  I downloaded, installed, and rebooted.

Then I went into my app in Visual Studio 2010, targeted the 4.0.3 framework, and this step requires the project to be closed and reopened, which I did.  I then rebuilt the project. I can successfully run the app inside Visual Studio. Then I published the app. But it cannot be run in the browser directly.  I get the error below.  Just to make sure, I re-registered the framework after getting the error, but no joy:

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
iisreset /stop
aspnet_regiis -i
iisreset /start


======================================
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error: 


Line 9:    </connectionStrings>
Line 10:   <system.web>
Line 11:     <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0.3" />
Line 12:     <authentication mode="None" />
Line 13:     <membership>
```

Comment: you are trying to run this with your local iis?

Comment: @Tim did you find a solution? If so, please post it and accept.

Answer (score 0):

The value you have entered for `targetFramework`, `4.0.3` is not valid.

From the documentation on the [`<compilation>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
targetFramework="2.0|3.0|3.5|4.0"
```

So, just drop the `.3` and you should be fine.

Comment: @Tim - What version of .NET is the application pool/website running under?